# Peak_pci usage with socketcan_interface

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I was planning to use [PCAN_M.2](https://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-M-2.473.0.html?&L=1) with ROS, but I did see a note in  [socketcan_interface](http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_interface)  saying that peak_pci has IRQ problems in section 3. Is it up to date? Is there anyone using any PCAN (mini-PCIe, M.2, etc) devices with ROS? I want to make sure that it works before purchasing it.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354311/peak_pci-usage-with-socketcan_interface/) by [ozzdemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/31442/ozzdemir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2020-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the past year or so I have been using the exact module in combination with an Intel NUC7i7DNBE (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/130394/intel-nuc-board-nuc7i7dnbe.html) using Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS1 melodic and I have not noticed any IRQ problems.

I have not used the socketcan_interface package, but instead used a CANOpen stack implementation in a custom node, but since all communication is abstracted from user space by the socketcan driver, I wonder how it would not work with the socketcan_interface package.

---

Originally posted by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) with karma: 247 on 2020-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ozzdemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/31442/ozzdemir/) on 2020-06-10**:
Thank you four your answer, that's what I thought also.

**Comment by [ESMCoolCode](https://answers.ros.org/users/109449/esmcoolcode/) on 2022-06-28**:
Hi! How do you "wake up" the peak hardware?
I am using the USB-CAN converter, which i have to "wake up" like this: http://codingadventures.org/2018/10/03/peak-can-usb-with-socketcan/
My pc also has a PCI express Peak module mounted, but cannot find it nor activate it .... :S